# Why does this not ask user for another input?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

This part of a larger project. Right now it's supposed to ask user for a string, calculate how many words are in it, print out the # of words, ask user if they want to do it again, then if they want to, ask for another string, and so on. But this only works fine the first time. After that, it takes the answer to the yes/no question as the test string. For example: I like coding. 3. Again? Yes/no. Yes. 1. Again? Yes/no... Can someone tell me how to fix this glitch?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string original[10] = { "hello", "sir", "madam", "officer", "stranger", "where", "is", "the", "my", "your" };
string translated[10] = { "ahoy", "matey", "proud beauty", "foul blaggart", "scurvy dog", "whar", "be", "th'", "me", "yer" };
string input;
string ans;

bool playAgain()
{
cout << "Another? yes/no: ";
cin >> ans;
if (ans.compare("yes") == 0) { return true; }
if (ans.compare("no") == 0) { return false; }
}

int getNumOfWords(string input)
{
    int numOfSpaces = 0;
    string current;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        current = input.at(i);
        if (current.compare(" ") == 0)
        {
            numOfSpaces++;
        }
    }
    return numOfSpaces + 1;
}

void play(string input)
{
    int numOfWords = getNumOfWords(input);
    cout << numOfWords << endl;
}

void start()
{
    getline(cin, input);
    play(input);
}

int main()
{
    bool playing;
    do
    {
        start();
        playing = playAgain();
    } while (playing);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Watch the case. In `playAgain`, you use a lower `y`, whereas in your sample answer, you use an uppercase `Y` in the word `Yes`. This leads to an error case where `ans` is neither `yes` nor `no` and the function doesn't return anything => Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I am suprised your compiler hasn't warned you about `playAgain()` not returning a value on all paths. I would recommend removing your if-statements and replacing them with `return ans == "yes";`, since `std::string` also has an `==` operator.

Comment: Thanks Jerry Goyal it works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

When `cin.getline()` reads from the input, there is a newline character left in the input stream, so it doesn't read your c-string. Use `cin.ignore()` beore calling `getline()`

```
void start()
{   cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, input);
    play(input);
}
```

Comment: To skip whitespace, I'd rather use `cin >> ws`, which *only* skips whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the difference between `getline` and `cout`. The former reads in the entire line up to and including the terminating `\n`, while `cout` will read only up to the `\n` or whitespace. The `cin` in your code reads in yes or no to `ans` (try printing it out immediately afterwards), but it doesn't account for the `\n`. Thus, when you call `getline` it finds the `\n` waiting in stdin, and so reads that into `input` instead of blocking until `cin` wasn't empty.